Cross validation doesn't work
I'm currently at the local uni listening to a data science presentation. We're here from work, I'm in DS/ML and have been for the last 7 years but my degree is comp sci, and thus I'm mostly self-taught in DS/ML.
The guy is telling us about how many things that are written about in DS articles don't actually work.
For example, he mentions that precision, recall and F1 scores are rarely used (instead he's favoring AUC).
But the other, more outlandish thing to me is how cross validation also shouldn't be used for business problems. He explained it doesn't work because it doesn't represent real life. In real life, your goal is not to predict for a random sample from the data distribution, but rather, you have to build a model from the past x years to predict the future y month's data.
So he said basically cross validation is useless and one should use walk forward optimization instead.
Firstly, how does that work? Is it just for validation or can it also be used for optimization? How?
Also, is CV really that useless? That's the most accepted form of validation in any article I've read about DS. But maybe this is where my self-taught knowledge is lacking.
Are there any more "myths" that are taller about a lot but don't actually work in real life scenarios?

I wonder if the main point by this individual was to avoid a basic cross validation that would use the future to predict the past. For temporal data, I am on board with this.

Of course standard cross-validation relies on some implicit assumptions (like i.i.d. data) that may be critically violated in such cases with dependence and/or systematic changes over time, so warning against naive use of cross-validation makes some sense. That doesn't mean it's generally useless. There are many situations in which it makes sense. If you want to automatically tell apart cats and dogs on images, time trends and dependence can be ignored.

@ChristianHennig yeah I think his point was that almost all corporate data is time series data regardless. Of course recognizing cats and dogs is not but almost all business use cases have a time component to it and you're modeling based on past x months to try to predict data in the next y months. So CV is "cheating".

It is true though that a lot of things that are written in articles don't actually work, but in most cases it is because techniques are used without fundamental understanding and hence mis-applied.  It is good to be skeptical, especially of things found on blogs.

Related to performance metrics


you have to build a model from the past x years to predict the future y month's data.

It sounds like this presenter has a heavy consideration for temporal data and wants to avoid using the future to predict the past. After all, unless you have a time machine, you don't get to use the future to make decisions in the past. A naive use of cross validation with temporal data will do so and should be avoided.
To say that cross validation does not work, however, takes it too far. Under assumptions that do fail with temporal data but might be reasonable for image data, cross validation makes sense, even if that is not the case in the work this individual does.

No, CV is not useless. But typical CV for cross-sectional data doesn't (usually) make sense for timeseries data. It is pretty common to tune parameters for time series models by optimizing a loss function that increases with your forecast error. But there are a ton of variations you could use. A common one is MAE for one step ahead forecast, but you could use any forecast horizon you want, weight the error relative to a naive forecast, etc. Rob Hyndman's "Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing" (https://robjhyndman.com/expsmooth/)has a couple of good sections on both metrics/loss and estimating the parameters.
